# How to populate DB values in content type field, drupal 7

Tags: 7, database

I have created a content type with 4 field in Drupal 7. One field is of list type, say for listing countries. I have tables in DB for saving country_id and country_name. Is there any way to connect the DB table and content type field? I want to list all these countries in the content type's country field.

Comment: How you storing country data ? In Custom table or using any entity(node, taxonomy) ?

Comment: @Rupesh OP said `I have tables in DB for saving country_id and country_name.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to install [Content Construction Kit (CCK)](https://drupal.org/project/cck) module. After installing this module you get a text field for Allowed value function in field setting of desired field. Put the function name here to get country list. Also put following function in a module.  You may have to modify query as per your requirement.  After doing all these thing you will able to get country list in that field.

[image]

```
function _get_country_list(){
    $country = array(); 
    $query = db_select('country', 'c');
    $query->fields('c', array('country_name','country_id'));
    $result = $query->execute();    
    if ($result) {
        while ($row = $result->fetchObject()) {
            $country[$row->country_id] = t($row->country_name);
        }
    }
    return $country;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You could make use of `views.api`

Implement views API

```
function MYMODULE_views_api() {
    return array(
        'api' => '3.0-alpha1', // Youre api version
        'path' => drupal_get_path('module','MYMODULE'). '/views',
    );
}
```

and create a file named `MYMODULE.views.inc` put it in `/views` folder

Read available functions here [`views.api.php`](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/)

Answer (score -2):

If I understood your question right, you was to show a list of countries in your content type field. There is a module for that. Take a look at the [countries module.](https://drupal.org/project/countries)

You can also use the [addressfield module](https://drupal.org/project/addressfield) if that fits your needs.

**Edit:**

you need to create a custom field widget in that case. Take a look at the [examples module](https://drupal.org/project/examples). Here's a [tutorial](http://getlevelten.com/blog/ian-whitcomb/defining-custom-field-types-drupal) for the same. Besides, there is a provision in countries module to disable specific countries.

Comment: OP is not looking for an alternate solution i think. OP is looking for a solution based on what s/he had.

Comment: @Badri Ofcourse, it is a solution. But I want only those countries that already there in my table.